# Test installed Python package

Tags: python, nose

To test my Python package I run in the source directory:
`python setup.py test`

If I understand correctly this tests the code in the source directory, not the installed package.

How can I test if the installation was successful.
Is it possible (or even common practice) to run the test suite on the installed packages?

Comment: Just install the tests along with the rest of your code?

Comment: So I navigate to the installation directory (e.g., `env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my-package`) and run `nosetests`? Is this how its normally done?

Comment: "Normally" I donot know but I see things like that every now and then to let users know whether everything is well after installation. Basically you need to provide the tests, a script to run them and a way to make sure the modules under test are imported from the right place (usually by means of `PYTHONPATH` and/or `sys.path` but the details may vary).

Comment: See [pandas installation docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/install.html#running-the-test-suite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Goyo I found a solution I am happy with.
I install the my package (let's call it `my-package`) including the tests through `setuptools` and run the following in the installation directory (e.g., `python-env/lib/python3.x/site-packages`):

```
nosetests my-package
```

Answer (score -4):

To test if a package was successfully installed on your machine, open python and type

```
import my_package
```

If you get no error, that means the package was successfully installed on your machine and you are good to go